# Understand a dynamical figure: stable manifold, node, domain of attraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Could someone please point out where the node, saddle and stable manifold are in this figure (as indicated in the caption)? I can see there is a focus, but I am not sure about the others. Thank you in advance.[image]

Source: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kouzn101/NBA/LAB2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus is at the center where the flow is spiraling in.

The stable manifold is the slant line coming down from the focus.
The saddle is the intersection of the slant line and the middle trajectory.

The node is intersection of the slant with the lower trajectory.

Comment: Why saddle is intersection of the slant line and the MIDDLE trajectory and node is intersection of the slant with the LOWER trajectory. ? I am not able to understand?

Comment: The flow near saddle is straight and near a node is tilted to get tangent to the axis.

Comment: nice, any references where this visualization is made?

Comment: Check a differential equation book, the section on planar phase portrait.

Comment: @BAYMAX You can do it in any tool where you have numerical integration of ODEs and plotting capabilities. It doesn't seem to use something very special here.

Comment: @BAYMAX However, since this is a MATCONT tutorial, I think it was done in MATLAB.